# Changing text binded to a resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, bind

I am trying to change my text binded to a resource file in run time.

For that I am following this tutorial:

https://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-05-10/localization_of_a_wpf_app_the_simple_approach

I simply created a WPF project, added 2 resource file, the first one named Resource.resx and the second one named Resource.pt-PT.resx, both of them have a field called Tag1. Then, I created a class with the code given in the previous tutorial:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class TranslationSource
            : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly TranslationSource instance = new TranslationSource();

        public static TranslationSource Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }

        private readonly ResourceManager resManager = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
        private CultureInfo currentCulture = null;

        public string this[string key]
        {
            get { return this.resManager.GetString(key, this.currentCulture); }
        }

        public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
        {
            get { return this.currentCulture; }
            set
            {
                if (this.currentCulture != value)
                {
                    this.currentCulture = value;
                    var @event = this.PropertyChanged;
                    if (@event != null)
                    {
                        @event.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class LocExtension
        : Binding
    {
        public LocExtension(string name)
            : base("[" + name + "]")
        {
            this.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            this.Source = TranslationSource.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally created a simple interface with the following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:TranslationSource"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Button Content="{x:Static ns:Loc Tag1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is what my Button_Click event is doing:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TranslationSource.Instance.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT");
    }
```

My current problem is connecting the TranslationSource code with my UI, the tutorial misses that part, probably because its something very simple, but unfortunatelly I am not very expert in WPF... Can anybody explain me what are the next steps?

Answer (score 0):

`TranslationSource` is not a namespace, it is a class name

change

```
xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:TranslationSource"
```

to

```
xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

or the appropriate namespace where you have the `TranslationSource` and `LocExtension` classes